# External properties of a Java class

Tags: java, eclipse, properties

I have a class file which requires a `.properties` external file with the configuration to run. I am able to run it via the terminal. However, I want to achieve this using eclipse.

```
java path/to/class --properties path/to/properties.properties
```

Does anyone know where and what do I need to set in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run->Run Configuration->Java Application->[Right Click] New   and in Arguments section provide your arguments.

Comment: The external properties file exists in the project folder, however, there are several packages inside. If i state `--properties file.properties` the path will not be recognised. Should be provide the complete path then?

Comment: Well try to add only package path also

Answer (score 1):

- eclipse will load properties from the root of your source directory
  or
- the eclipse runner (i.e. running any class) has a tab that allows you to manually specify jvm args.